# project pixel location for image stitching

Tags: python, image, opencv, projection

I am working on a python project which involves stitching high resolution images which are mostly greyscale. The method of extracting features is not viable for this project as the images do not contain enough key points/descriptors for feature extracting with algorithms such as SIFT/SURF.

I have attempted to predict a pixels location between 2 images using the intrinsic matrix of the camera to create a rotation matrix but this was unsuccessful.

is it possible to project pixels from 1 image into another in this way at all or should I be looking at something else? possibly working with the extrinsic matrix?

the camera uses a 600mm lens with a full frame sensor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would take some pictures of a test target that *does* have key points for alignment.  As long as the alignment remains consistent you'll be able to reuse those coordinates to stitch together subsequent images.

Comment: P.S. there's no way you'll be able to figure out alignment based on the physical layout of the system - too many variables.